# Float to IBM Floating 32bit

Tags: java

Кто сталкивался с такими вещами, как конвертирование значений из **float** в **IBM Floating 32bit** и обратно? Решаю сей вопрос на **Java**, понимая, что нужно отталкиваться от таких понятий как mantissa, sign, exponent (судя по статье в Wiki: IBM Floating 32bit Architecture) получается такой код для нахождения вышеперечисленных величин:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float d = -157.1817f;
        String binaryBits = Integer.toBinaryString(Float.floatToIntBits(d));
        char[] arrayCharact = new char[binaryBits.length()];
        arrayCharact = binaryBits.toCharArray();

        StringBuilder sign = new StringBuilder();
        sign.append(arrayCharact[0]);

        StringBuilder exponent = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k=1; k<7; k++)
            exponent.append(arrayCharact[k]);

        StringBuilder mantissa = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k=7; k<31; k++)
            mantissa.append(arrayCharact[k]);
        System.out.println(sign + "\n" + exponent + "\n" + mantissa);
    }
```

}

Как быть дальше? что делать с этими переменными? на сколько верен подход? и правильно ли я рассуждаю, что это перевод float в IBM Floating 32bit?

P.S. по образованию не программист, но для написания диссера оч пригодится. **спасибо**.

Comment: @bersano, вот что делать с этими переменными? это вопрос к Вам.

Вы сейчас их просто печатаете, видите нолики и единички. Может и достаточно?

Чуть по делу. Цикл для получения **единственного**(!!!) знакового бита - *это круто*!

В остальном (если exponent и mantissa действительно нужны вам в виде строк символов), а почему бы и нет? На первый взгляд изображение в ноликах и единичках правильное.

--

Если же sign, exponent и mantissa в дальнейшем должны использоваться как целые числа, то я бы вообще не преобразовывал к строкам, а растащил результат вызова Float.floatToIntBits(d) сдвигами.

Comment: спасибо, немного поясню печатаю строки для проверки решения(на той же ссылке Wiki, есть разбор выделения этих переменных с другим числом, но конечного исхода как их использовать не нашел).

Да, с циклом в 1 строку это слишком мудрено, по правлю :)

Перевести из строк в числа или изначально получать их в числах, используя сдвиги, можно переписав кусок кода, но ни на один из заданных вопросов это не отвечает.

Comment: Ну и учоные пошли - еще один диссер а ля Шамхалов & Ко?

Comment: @bersano, что-то, похоже, я не до конца понял Ваши вопросы. 

Уточните, Вы хотите перевести Float из IEEE 754 (Float.floatToIntBits() представление в нем) в IBM?

Вообще, почетче сформулируйте вопрос. ("Как быть дальше? что делать с этими переменными?" - это вопросы к Вам).

Сейчас, насколько понимаю, вы печатаете битовое представление в IEEE (а насколько оно совпадает с IBM надо изучать).

Кстати, а диссерт о чем?

Comment: @avp да, все верно, хочу перевести из IEEE754 в IBM Floating 32bit и обратно, хотелось бы понять как переводить.
диссер по преобразованию сейсмических данных. используется формат SEG-Y, в котором как раз таки используется именно IBM Floating 32bit.

Comment: @bersano, удачи. 

Вторая ссылка в моем комментарии к ответу @Barmaley как раз на пару программ (IEEE <-> IBM).

Правда, они на Си. Надеюсь, на Java (если она Вам ближе) сами переведете.

 Форматы (single-presition 32 bit в битах) [IEEE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и [IBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture)

Answer (score 1):

Давным давно 100 лет назад решал схожую задачу, но на C. Был массив бинарных данных сгенерированный IBM System/360 надо было их прочитать и сконвертить из кодировки IBM в стандартную IEEE кодировку. Делал примерно так:

1. Читаем биты IBM
2. Парсим биты, раскурочиваем до состояния sign/mantissa/exponent
3. Записываем биты в формате [IEEE double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format)
4. Проводим каст на `double`

За давностью лет исходник ясен пень уже не сохранился. Простое гугление дает ссылку на [исходник на C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492449/Transform-between-IEEE-IBM-or-VAX-floating-point-n)
Полагаю сконвертировать код с C# на Java не составит труда (а оно надо?)

**Update:**
Набросал по быстрому парсинг битов `float` формата IEEE:

```
    float d = -157.1817f;
    int bits=Float.floatToRawIntBits(d);

    int sign = ((bits >> 31) == 0) ? 1 : -1; //знак на 31-м бите
    int exp = ((bits >> 23) & 0xff);  //экспонента с 30 по 23 биты
    int mantissa = (exp == 0) ?  (bits & 0x7fffff) << 1 : (bits & 0x7fffff) | 0x800000; //мантисса
    System.out.println("sign="+sign+", exp="+exp+", mantissa="+mantissa);

    //проверка
    double check=sign*mantissa*Math.pow(2.0, exp-150);
    System.out.println(check);
```

Comment: Аналогично нашел (кроме описаний в Виках) [вопрос о конвертации](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399486/ibm-to-ieee-floating-point-conv) и [ответ на Си](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t438469-c-code-for-converting-ibm-370-floating-point-to-ieee-754-a.html)

Comment: @Barmaley, только IMHO от exp надо 127, а не 150 отнимать.

Comment: @Barmaley @avp спасибо, направили в нужное русло, пойду пыхтеть над этим делом дальше :)

Comment: @avp нет, в Java, как известно int/long знаковый, поэтому при конверсии мантиссы возникает сдвижка на 23, которая компенсируется показателем экспоненты 23+127=150

Comment: Да, Вы правы - 150.